# Error While Installing Face_recognition in python3.5.2 windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already have dlib 19.1.0 and open cv 3.4.5 and numpy,scipy packages with advanced version but by using

```
pip install face_recognition
```

im getting following errors..Please can anyone help me what i did wrongly..

```
Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/ed/ad9a28042f373d4633fc8b49109b623597d6f193d3bbbef7780a5ee8eef2/face_recognition-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.15.4)
Collecting dlib>=19.7 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/8d/e4ddf60452e2fb1ce3164f774e68968b3f110f1cb4cd353235d56875799e/dlib-19.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 (from face_recognition)
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python35\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (5.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqlch36v\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-de03y7mf --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\python35\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  ImportError: cannot import name 'cmake'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 188, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 127, in run
      cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 118, in get_cmake_version
      out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
    File "c:\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
      **kwargs).stdout
    File "c:\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 708, in run
      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition-models, face-recognition
  Found existing installation: dlib 19.1.0
    Uninstalling dlib-19.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled dlib-19.1.0
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqlch36v\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tjyw2jml\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\python35\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name 'cmake'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 127, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\setup.py", line 118, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "c:\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "c:\python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 708, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of dlib
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqlch36v\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tjyw2jml\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqlch36v\dlib\
```

Actually i tried with some other installation keywords and tried to rectified error but 'm getting same errors when i used pip install face_recognition and my python version is 3.5.2 and i tried with wheel files also with specified version of python and face_recognition.
Following wheel files are i have tried wheel files..
https://pypi.org/simple/face-recognition/

Comment: Do you have `cmake` installed and added to your `PATH`?

Comment: i have installed using pip commend pip install cmake and cmake installed in my sitepackages and can you tell me how to add cmake to my path.

Comment: is it mandatory to install cmake for face_recognition?

Comment: i have installed and added path but again its getting same error only

Comment: Guess it'll need more debugging. There's an excellent tutorial [here](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508). Hope it helps.

Comment: [Installation of Face_Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732194)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello for this problem make this

step 1:

```
pip install cmake dlib
```

step 2:

```
pip install face-recognition
```

> If you have the problem by dlib check this

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
```