# RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, dlib

I have already installed CMake by `pip install cmake` and tried to install `face_recognition` but it still gives me a RuntimeError. I'm using 'Python 3.7.3, x32'

I also tried to install the `dlib` by `pip install dlib` since it is one of the reasons why I can't install `face_recognition`.

```
C:\Users\user>python -m pip install cmake
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (3.14.4)

C:\Users\user>python -m pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-24vk6act\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yf2kdjpx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-24vk6act\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-24vk6act\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-24vk6act\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-24vk6act\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
        "\n*******************************************************************\n")
    RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
    *******************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-24vk6act\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yf2kdjpx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-24vk6act\dlib\
```

Answer (score 29):

Download and install dlib wheel from [here](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/)

Then `pip install face_recognition`

---

- `pip install cmake`
- In [visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#), Individual Components
  tab,Visual C++ tools for Cmake checkbox under Compilers,build tools
  and runtimes Section
- On Visual Studio Command prompt run, `pip install face_recognition`

[Source](https://smartmanoj.blogspot.com/2018/11/install-python-facerecognition-module.html)

Comment: do i have to install visual studio 2019 or any other version? even though i am just using visual studio code alone?

Comment: Or try the dlib wheel

Comment: No need to install VSCode. I used create python virtual environment version 3.6 and installed `dlib` with wheel file as it was supporting upto version 3.6. Then did `pip install cmake` & then `pip install face_recognition`.

Answer (score 12):

What works for is ...
After getting lots of Red Errors, I run following

1. `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`
2. `pip install cmake`
3. `pip install face_recognition`

Even the error says me to reinstall `VS Code for c++`. but above sequential installation works.

```
Python version was 3.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try install dlib using conda
`conda install -c conda-forge dlib`

Comment: Please provide other alternate installation methods using other package managers.

Comment: This has worked for me. Firstly you need to have a visual studio installer where you install CMake and other Microsoft build tools and then just by following the above command you can install dlib and then face recognition library

Answer (score 0):

For me, non of the solutions didn't work. Then, I downloaded all libraries in face_recognition package manually (like "pip install dlib==19.7", "pip install Click". At last, I installed face recognition with this command "pip install --no-deps face_recognition"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).