# Python face_recognition won't install

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, window, face-recognition

I am trying to install the library for face_recognition. I keep getting the error "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib" I've already installed CMake and dlib, and when I try and re-install it using pip I get a confirmation they are already installed. I also tried adding the library through the setting in PyCharm (where I can see both CMake and dlib are installed) and is still gives an error.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake` before the `pip install`.

Comment: I've ran pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade which came back that all libraries Requirement already satisfied: 
Its showing cmake==3.21.2

Comment: I found that https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732194/10749317

Comment: Same thing. Downloaded locally and used pip to try install the dlib from the site in that post - "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib"